# Grab files from Azure DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to do something I thought was super simple... I want to grab generated files (not built) and copy them to an Azure Blob storage

In my Build the last step of my azure-pipeline.yml look like this:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy generated content'
  inputs: 
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/output'
    contents: '**\*' 
    targetFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)/drop
    cleanTargetFolder: true
```

Then, in the Release I have an Azure CLI step with the inline following code:

```
az storage blob upload-batch -s "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)" -d '$web' --account-name frankdemo--account-key '_MYKEY_'
```

I try different combinations of paths, but nothing works...

**Q:** What should I put as **targetFolder** in my build and "**-s**" in my release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add step so it will publish artifacts

```
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Server'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: Server
```

Then in your release you can use "Azure File Copy" to copy from your release to blob storatge

Comment: I thought  CopyFiles and PublishBuildArtifacts were doing the same job. Except that with CopyFiles  I could specify the source...

Comment: copy is like preparation of your data, then you tell to publish. Could be that before publish you need to copy data from multiple places